# How to keep the text inside the column of table

Tags: tables, columns

I have the following table in TeX.

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering \footnotesize
\caption{Schedule and Milestones}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.4in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|p{.2in}|} 
\hline
\textbf{Phase1} \\ \hline
Month & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 &   18 \\ \hline
Milestones  &   &   &   &   &   & Software Delivery &   &   &   &   &   & Software Delivery  &   &    &    &   &   &  Software Delivery   \\ \hline
Tasks & U1U2E1E2 & U1,U2,E1,E2 & U1,U2,E1,E2 & U1,U2,E1,E2 & U1,U2,E1,E2,E4 & U1,U2,E1,E2,E4 & U1,U2,E1,E2 & U1,U2,E1,E2 & U1,U2,E1,E2  & U1,U2,U3,E1,E2,E3 &   U1,U2,E1,E2,E4 & U1,U2,E1,E2,E4 & U1,U2,E1,E2 & U1,U2,E1,E2 & U1,U2,E1,E2 & U1,U2,U3,E1,E2,E3 & U1,U2,E1,E2,E4 & U1,U2,E1,E2,E4  \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\label{Schedule}
\end{table}
```

In spite of defining the size as `p{.2in}`, the text inside the columns are crossing the boundary. The text in the task row is not visible and crossing the boundary. Why is it like that?! Also, what other options I can use to make the table contents more readable?

[image]

Comment: tex doesn't by default hyphenate the first word of a paragraph and probably can't hyphenate DARPA you could use Soft\-wa\-re and DA\-RP\-A but do you really want want text set that way it is not really readable, try to use shorter text or rotate the text or ..

Comment: How can I use the rotate option?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Plain TeX and pdfLaTeX won't hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, but LuaLaTeX does. :-)

Comment: @DamanjitSingh http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=rotate+header

Comment: @Mico e-tex is modern for me:-)

Comment: Please read the first chapter of the booktabs documentation:http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf It will help you a lot!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Rotate option seems complex to me in this case.Also why the text in the Tasks row is not line breaked?

Comment: @DamanjitSingh you have no space after the comma so tex will not break it automatically

Comment: You also can use the `lscape` package to have your table in landscape orientation (`\beginlandscape} … \end{landscape}`) and combine it with `tabularx`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it is complicated, it just means `\rotatebox{90}{Software Delivery}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

- Typeset the table in landscape mode, e.g., by loading the `rotating` package and using its `sidewaystable` environment.
- Insert spaces after each comma in the "Tasks" row, to let line breaks be inserted as needed. (Actually, I don't think the commas are even necessary; just provide spaces...)
- Use LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX to compile the code: LuaLaTeX will hyphenate the first word in a paragraph, whereas pdfLaTeX does not. This matters for the words "Milestones" and "Software".

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!ht]
\centering \footnotesize
\caption{Schedule and Milestones} \label{Schedule}
\begin{tabular}{| p{.4in} *{18}{|p{.2in}} |} 
\hline
\textbf{Phase1} \\ 
\hline
Month & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\ 
\hline
Milestones  &   &   &   &   &   & Software Delivery &   &   &   &   &   & Software Delivery  &   &    &    &   &   &  Software Delivery   \\ 
\hline
Tasks & U1, U2, E1, E2 & U1, U2, E1, E2 & U1, U2, E1, E2 & U1, U2, E1, E2 & U1, U2, E1, E2, E4 & U1, U2, E1, E2, E4 & U1, U2, E1, E2 & U1, U2, E1, E2 & U1, U2, E1, E2  & U1, U2, U3, E1, E2, E3 &   U1, U2, E1, E2, E4 & U1, U2, E1, E2, E4 & U1, U2, E1, E2 & U1, U2, E1, E2 & U1, U2, E1, E2 & U1, U2, U3, E1, E2, E3 & U1, U2, E1, E2, E4 & U1, U2, E1, E2, E4  \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: While the first code batch may make the table "work" in a very minimal sort of way, further improvements are certainly possible:

- To achieve better readability through a more "open" look of the table, get rid of all vertical lines and replace `\hline` with the macros of the `booktabs` package: `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule`. Move the word "Month" to a position above (instead of the left of) the month numbers.
- Automatically exploit the full available width by using a `tabularx` environment. Use a modified form of that package's `X` column type for columns 2 through 19 of the table.
- Get rid of the commas between the task letter/number combos.
- Load the `caption` package to get more spacing between the table's caption and body.

I'm confident you like the resulting look:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,caption}
%% Create ragged-right versions of the "X" and "p" column types:
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!ht]
\footnotesize
\caption{Schedule and Milestones} \label{Schedule}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{0.35in} *{3}{YYYYYP{0.6in}}@{}} 
\toprule
Phase~1 &  \multicolumn{18}{c}{Month}\\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-19}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \\ 
\midrule
Milestones  
&   &   &   &   &   & Software Delivery to DARPA
&   &   &   &   &   & Software Delivery to DARPA 
&   &   &   &   &   & Software Delivery to DARPA \\ 
\midrule
Tasks & U1 U2 E1 E2 & U1 U2 E1 E2 & U1 U2 E1 E2 & U1 U2 E1 E2 & U1 U2 E1 E2 E4 & U1 U2 E1 E2 E4 & U1 U2 E1 E2 & U1 U2 E1 E2 & U1 U2 E1 E2  & U1 U2 U3 E1 E2 E3 &   U1 U2 E1 E2 E4 & U1 U2 E1 E2 E4 & U1 U2 E1 E2 & U1 U2 E1 E2 & U1 U2 E1 E2 & U1 U2 U3 E1 E2 E3 & U1 U2 E1 E2 E4 & U1 U2 E1 E2 E4  \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should load `caption`: the spacing between caption and table is too tight. Don't forget LaTeX doesn't permute `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`.

Comment: @Bernard - You're right, the spacing is too tight. I think I'll post a second answer, which implements this point and also brings about a few other improvements (such as using the macros of the `booktabs` package).

Comment: Why don't you use tabularx with a width set to `\textheight` since it's in landscape orientation? This way the X columns will be slightly wider (~ 35%, I would say).

Comment: @Bernard - The values of `\textheight` and `\textwidth` are automatically switched inside a `sidewaystable` environment. (This is different from the behavior of the `lscape`, `pdflscape`, etc packages...) I find this switch of the two text block parameters very intuitive and helpful, as for me the "width" of the text block when in landscape mode is the larger of the two page dimensions.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that. Personally, I always use `lscape`. This is quite helpful indeed.

Comment: @Bernard  lscape has to cope with page breaking and adding the header and footer (in portrait mode) and they are often in boxes specified `\textwidth` wide, which is why I didn't make `lscape` switch `\textwidth`